# is float16 supported in matlab?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, ieee-754

Does MATLAB support float16 operations? If so, how to convert a double matrix to float16? I am doing an arithmetic operation on a large matrix where 16-bit floating representation is sufficient for my representation. Representing by a double datatype takes 4 times more memory.

Comment: Be aware that there is a significant performance impact when working with half-precision floats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your matrix full? Otherwise, try `sparse` -- saves a lot of memory if there's lots of zero-valued elements.

AFAIK, `float16` is not supported. Lowest you can go in `float`-datatype is with `single`, which is a 32-bit datatype:

```
A = single( rand(50) );
```

You could multiply by a constant and cast to `int16`, but you'd lose precision.

Comment: Excellent. I am storing a large histogram where value of each bin do not exceed 16bit precision. uint16 didn't support matrix multiplications. Thanks for the heads up on sparse command.

Answer (score 5):

The numeric classes, which Matlab supports out of the box are the following:

```
int8
int16
int32
int64
uint8
uint16
uint32
uint64
single (32-bit float)
double (64-bit float)
```

plus the complex data type. So no 16-bit floats, unfortunately.

On Mathworks file exchange, there seems to be a [half-precision float library](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23173-ieee-754r-half-precision-floating-point-converter). It requires MEX, however.

Comment: I gave a shot with half-precision float libary before posting here, it complained that it doesn't support non IEEE 754r.

Comment: @ssk: IEEE 754r explicitly contains half-precision floats (along with single, double and quad precision). From my understanding, it should work, thus. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This might be an old question, but I found it in search for a similiar problem (half precision in matlab).

Things seemed to have changed in time:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/half.html

Half-precision seems to be supported nativeley by matlab now.

Comment: Key point: this is not supported in the core MATLAB installation, only by the [Fixed-Point Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/index.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers.